# Using JBoss to establish a Mysql JTA connection, it ends in an error

Tags: jboss, wildfly, java-ee-6

I'm trying to set up a MySQL connection using Jboss. For this I take the JTA approach. I have adjusted everything so far, but always get an error when deploying:

My standalone.xml looks like this:

```
 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>xxx</user-name>
                    <password>xxx</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
  </datasource>
```

The persistence.xml has the following structure:

```
<persistence-unit name="TestJPA" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>de.jpa.test.Kunden</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And here the resulting error:

```
09:11:56,124 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "TestJPA.war")]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MySqlDS"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"TestJPA.war#TestJPA\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MySqlDS]",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"TestJPA.war#TestJPA\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MySqlDS]"
]
}
```

***EDIT***

```
 <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
 </drivers>
```

Comment: You must have some previous error, is your driver properly created as you didn't paste that part of the configuration ?

Comment: Have you installed MySQL connector as a Wildfly module?

Comment: probably you didn't add the MySQL driver  jar check this issue for more details how to solve it : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633933/jboss-operationadd-failed